# take access token from Shared Preferences and pass in base url next time

Tags: api, kotlin, retrofit, sharedpreferences, okhttp

I want to know how can I access my token stored in Shared Preferences and pass it in the url when required.

RetrofitClient.kt file :

class OAuthInterceptor(private val tokenType: String, private val access_token: String):
Interceptor {

```
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    var request = chain.request()
    request = request.newBuilder().header("Authorization", "$tokenType $access_token").build()

    return chain.proceed(request)
    } 
}


 val client =  OkHttpClient.Builder()
.addInterceptor(OAuthInterceptor("Bearer", access_token))
.build()

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("___________________")
.client(client)
.build()

    object RetrofitClient {

    private const val BASE_URL = "_______"

    private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor { chain ->
            val original = chain.request()

            val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .method(original.method, original.body)

            val request = requestBuilder.build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }.build()

    val instance: MyApi by lazy{
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()

        retrofit.create(MyApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

Below is my SharedPrefManager file :

class SharedPrefManager private constructor(private val mCtx: Context) {

```
    val user: User
        get() {
            val sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            return User(
                sharedPreferences.getString(user.access_token, ""),
                sharedPreferences.getString(user.user_id.toString(), "" ),
                sharedPreferences.getString(user.user_name, ""),
                sharedPreferences.getString(user.status, ""),
                sharedPreferences.getString(user.role_id,""),
                sharedPreferences.getString(user.phone, "")
            )
        }


    fun saveUser(user: User) {

        val sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()

        editor.putString("access_token", user.access_token)
        editor.putString("id", user.user_id)
        editor.putString("username", user.user_name)
        editor.putString("status", user.status)
        editor.putString("role_id", user.role_id)
        editor.putString("phone", user.phone)

        editor.apply()

    }

    fun clear() {
        val sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.clear()
        editor.apply()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val SHARED_PREF = "my_shared_pref"
        private var mInstance: SharedPrefManager? = null
        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(mCtx: Context): SharedPrefManager {
            if (mInstance == null) {
                mInstance = SharedPrefManager(mCtx)
            }
            return mInstance as SharedPrefManager
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the name of the save preference when retrieving them.
Try to change your `SharedPrefManager` `get` method like this:

```
get() {
    val sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    return User(
        sharedPreferences.getString("access_token", ""),
        sharedPreferences.getString("id", "" ),
        sharedPreferences.getString("username", ""),
        sharedPreferences.getString("status", ""),
        sharedPreferences.getString("role_id",""),
        sharedPreferences.getString("phone", "")
    )
}
```